# WallpaperService.Engine.onTouchEvent do not receive ACTION_MOVE event

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

WallpaperService.Engine.onTouchEvent do not receive ACTION_MOVE event when is Live Wallpaper in use, but events work good on preview.

Do someone have similar problem and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling setTouchEventsEnabled(true) in your Engine constructor.

I ran into the same problem while trying to do Vogella's [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html), and that solved it for me.